# Problems compiling netcat for MIPS in ubuntu

Tags: c, compiler-construction, mips

I'm new with this and I am a little messed with it:

I'm trying to compile netcat source code for MIPS in order to deploy it in my router, what I do is:

Download the toolchain for mips: mips-linux-gcc

Download netcat source and expand it to a folder

```
cd path/to/netcatsource

Execute:
CC=path/to/compiler/mips-linux-gcc ./configure --host=mips-linux

make
```

The make command works fine and trying the file command over compiled netcat file displays:

```
file netcat
OUTPUT: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

For me everything seems fine, but if I execute ./netcat on my ubuntu box it works, and once I upload it to the router it displays the following error:

```
# ./netcat
Segmentation fault
```

This is the /proc/cpuinfo from my router:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : 963281T_TEF
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Broadcom4350 V7.5
BogoMIPS                : 319.48
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : no
hardware watchpoint     : no
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available

unaligned exceptions            : 1395
```

Could anyone help me with this?
Regards

Comment: Do you have a `gdb` on your router? If so try debugging. On the other hand you could try `strace` system call to what's actually happening.

Comment: Hi @KiaMorot, I don't have none of those tools. I also installed busybox-mips to get more tools but it's not included.

Comment: Then is hard to tell what's happening. You could try some other toolchains: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=637454

Comment: Try to figure out (e..g from configure output) which specific MIPS arch is supported, and make sure that your broadcom is a superset of that.

Comment: One related question. If it is compiled for MIPS proc, could it work on mu ubuntu box?

Comment: @Marco van de Voort, this is the entire output of configure: http://pastebin.com/CXap9Sjz

Comment: What are the make errors/warnings?

Comment: @Joe I missunderstood the output, actually there are no Warning or Errors in make output.

Comment: Then edit your question to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

*(I couldn't add a comment due to, I do not have enough points)*

Try to **static compile** the source code
The problem may be happening because you do not have the necessary libraries on the router, maybe the binary is pointing to **ld-linux.so** and the router uses **ld-uclibc.so**.
 So try static build...

**UPDATE**
I recomend the **buildroot** toolchain, which by the way include netcat and many other tools like busybox